# Can an MQTT publisher also subscribe to the same topic that it is publishing?

Tags: mqtt, publish, subscribe, broker

I am writing data to an MQTT broker with host IP: 85.119.83.194 using EZware Plus software and I am also trying to be able to read the data in SCADA software called Indusoft.  I am able to write to the MQTT broker from the EZware Plus software and see it in the Indusoft software.  I am able to see the data coming through in the MQTT broker software TT3 as well.  However, when I try to change the value in the Indusoft software I can see it in the TT3 MQTT broker software but it won't show up in the Ezware Plus software even though I am subscribing to it.  Is it even possible to Publish and subscribe to the same topic?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to publish and subscribe to the same topic and any client that does so will see every message published to that topic (including it's own) under normal circumstances.

It is possible that the broker has enabled access controls for specific users which may mean that you can only publish to the topic in question. The broker will allow the client to subscribe to the topic but will just not send any messages for that topic to the client.